Android Studio shows the android dev language but not IOS in project creation
when i create a new flutter project
I'm a new in flutter development. When I create a project, it only display "Android language" (android development language java or kotlin).
But not showing anything about IOS development languages like (Objective C or Swift).
So is there a way for it to display "iOS language" ? I have tried but it's still don't show up.

When creating a new Flutter project, it defaults to Kotlin for Android and Swift for iOS. You can specify the native language during creation with the --android-language and --ios-language flags.
flutter create <project_name> --android-language java --ios-language objc

For an existing project, delete the ios and/or android directory and run the flutter create command with the appropriate flags.

Ok, thank you very much. I will try it.
